# Cleaning nose with hands in an awkward manner

Tags: sentence

I am trying to find a sentence or phrase that would best describe "Cleaning nose with your hand" but in an awkward manner, so that you straighten your hands then start pushing it across the nasal path from finger tips to the palm.

I need to use this phrase in a [question of mine](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56959/how-does-one-politely-stop-other-people-from-using-your-mouse), but I am not able to find correct words in English or able to search it on Google for a picture as I am not sure what would be the correct words.

Comment: Ignacio, does this picture describe what you are looking for? http://viralportal.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/pick-nose-boost-immunity.jpg

Comment: @A.P. thanks but in picture person is using finger, but I am talking about rubbing your hand across your nose -  down to upside way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general term that would work is **"wiping your nose"**.

If you need to refer to the upward motion of the palm that catches the snot, consider the informal "allergic salute":

> Some people refer to this colloquially as the **"allergic salute"** because the upward-swiping hand is "saluting".

(http://www.wikihow.com/Wipe-Your-Nose-on-Your-Hands)

[image]

Comment: [Wipe your nose on your sleeve](https://www.google.it/search?q=Wiping+one%27s+nose+on+their+sleeve&oq=Wiping+one%27s+nose+on+their+sleeve&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22wipe+your+nose+on+your+sleeve%22&tbm=bks), was going to be my answer, too late, another wooden spoon for me, I'm afraid :P

Comment: @Mari-LouA :) Made the pic smaller, btw.